# I am not receiving the vox populi badge, and I am not allowed to vote anymore

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting-badges

Whenever I try to vote, I get `Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 2 hours.`, it has been like that for over an hour, and I still hadn't received my Vox Pupuli badge.

My stats are showing that I voted 39 times only.

Comment: You need to vote on a minimum of 10 questions to reach that 40.

Comment: You haven't voted on enough questions early enough. If you wait too long with voting on questions, you don't get 40 votes.

Comment: Especially on heavy loaded Stack Exchange sites like Stack Overflow badges won't be awarded instantly. Give it a while and you will get your badge if you fulfill the requirements.